# Unity deforms every prefab that I create

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have problem with Unity prefabs. Every time I create a nice looking UI in main scene and I want to store it as prefab for later usage if I open this prefab it's deformed(random cliping, moved UI elements in different directions, ... such a mess). If I try to fix this prefab in prefab editor to make it nice looking like before and then if I insert this back to scene it's totally unusable. It creates bigger mess than before in prefab editor... I don't know what to do. Editor throws no errors btw.

In first image is nice looking UI(example already created). In 2nd image is prefab editor. Text is totally out of panel and 3rd is from back in scene (means removed old one UI and place stored prefab from folder) the panel is gone.

[Imgur - images are orded by scene to prefab editor and back to scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJX4G.jpg)

On those images you can  see a 3 elements... but if I make more complex UI, it's clipping through each other in prefab editor and also back in scene.

Unity version: 2019.1.7f1

Comment: This is probably due to how anchors and pivots work on RectTransform objects. That is: Unity is doing everything 100% correctly (you're just giving it values that are only correct for the *one specific aspect ratio* and parent transform because you're using your anchors wrong).

Comment: Danke schön. In this light the questions seems stupid.